# How to create file in a directory using shell commands in django

Tags: django-models, django-templates, django-views

Iam doing a project in django where i have to concatenate some log files and place it in the new file. How to create a file using shell commands in django???

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 0):

Django, is just a Python framework. So, what you can do in Django is pretty much what you can do in Python.

In Python, the way to open (and create) files is with `open(filename, mode)`.

```
>>> f = open('testing', 'w')
```

After you have a file object, you can write on it, and after doing everything you needed to do, close it.

```
>>> f.write('Hello world!')
>>> f.close()
>>> f = open('testing', 'r')
>>> f.read()
'Hello world!'
```